# Is it possible to display a message box whose text is refreshing during execution, under a Windows service?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services

Due to project specifications, I need to build my application as Windows service. Also, I need to display a box where I must print every task the service is completing. Maybe, using WCF Service is too complicated for my needs. And I was thinking in `WTSSendMessage` function.

Then, using `WTSSendMessage`, is it possible to display a message box from a Windows Service and keep the box while its text is refreshing with the tasks that service is doing? Is that the right appproach to get something like that as Windows service?

Update: Seeing Ken's response, if it is possible in any way, I'd prefer to have only the Windows Service running whiout any client side.

Comment: What do you mean by "Due to project specifications"?

Comment: As far as using the actual `MessageBox` object, probably not, but it is very easy to simply create your own "message box" and update the text after it is displayed as you wish.

Comment: @Ian, I mean I haven't other option that develop the sw as Windows Service.

Comment: @AdSsa I get that. I just want to know the reason. A service generally has no UI.

Comment: @user1438893, how could I display a message box without using forms or `MessageBox`? I'm not used to work with this...

Comment: @Ian, the app, as service, will be waiting for some specific events. Those  kind of events will fire some tasks, the user have to be informed about the app progress and sometimes he could make a decision.

Comment: @AdSsa You have not said why this needs to be a service. A service has no UI.

Comment: @Ian, why a service and not an app that starts when Win start, for example? I don't really know why designers made that decision but that is something I can't change.

Comment: You can have any app start when windows starts.